# Howt o get the t-sql statements being used to Update a DataSet

Tags: c#, sql, dataset

I've a c# DataSet object with one table in it, and put some data in it and i've made some changes to that dataset (by code).

Is there a way to get the actual t-sql queries this dataset will perform on the sql server when I update the dataset to the database with code that looks something like this:

```
var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdText, connection);
var affected = dataAdapter.Update(updatedDataSet);
```

I want to know what queries this dataset will fire to the database so I can log these changes to a logfile in my c# program.

Answer (score 1):

You can subscribe to the [`RowUpdating`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.rowupdating.aspx) and [`RowUpdated`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.rowupdated.aspx) events of the `SqlDataAdapter`. They will tell you the `SqlCommand` that's about to be executed or which has just executed.

You can affect the current and future updating rows by setting the [`Status`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.rowupdatingeventargs.status.aspx) property of the [`SqlRowUpdatingEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlrowupdatingeventargs.aspx) supplied with the event. It is of type [`UpdateStatus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.updatestatus.aspx), so you can tell it to skip the current or all future rows.

Comment: Ok, next question, but how can I prevent that the queries are actually executed on the database when I will do an .update on the dataadapter?

Answer (score 0):

ask out the SqlCommand objects of the SqlDataAdapter

Comment: Sorry, but where can I find (which property) these SqlCommand objects?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.updatecommand(v=VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could build a wrapper around the `System.Data.SqlClient` Provider (*Ex. the provider registered in the config file as...* `providerName="System.Data.SqlClient`"). Essentially an intercept proxy you would have access to all the information passing through the Provider and could siphon-off what you need, intercept, modify, aggregate and/or enrich it. This is a bit more advanced but opens the door to capture a whole range of information and could be inserted/replaced/removed as a separate layer of concern.